# SQL - When using an ORM, does it sometimes make sense to not use a pivot table for many_to_many relationships?

Tags: sql, postgresql, ecto

For the following hypothetical use case, I'm trying to understand why it may be desirable to have a pivot table instead of an alternative solution (outlined below).

## Hypothetical Use Case

Let’s say that a movie has many actors and that an actor can belong to more than one movie.

## "Standard" Pivot Table Solution

As outlined in this [lesson (using Elixir's Ecto library)](https://elixirschool.com/en/lessons/ecto/associations/#many-to-many), the "standard" solution recommends using a `movies_actors` pivot table, and both the `movies` and `actors` tables reference this `movies_actors` table.

## Alternative Solution

Instead, could we achieve the same result by having the concept of a list of ids?

- `actor` belongs to one or more `movies` by having the `actors` table include a `movie_ids` field (which is a list)
- `movie` has many `actors` by having the `movies` table include a `actor_ids` field (which is a list)

## Question

Is one solution preferable? Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should not use the "alternative solution" of storing arrays of referenced `id`s to model an many-to-many relationship. It seems simpler at first glance, but it will hurt you later.

You should write a simple test case for both scenarios and create test tables with a realistic number of entries and relationships (it doesn't matter if the data are artificial and repeating). Then try to write a join between the two tables. You will find that with the "alternative solution", the query looks much more complicated (at best, it will involve strange operators like `@>`) and doesn't perform as well (you can only get a nested loop join).

There is a good reason to keep data in the [first normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form) – it is better adapted to the way relational databases process data.

Of course this "normal form" stuff has to be taken with a grain of salt: it is fine to use an array to store data, as long as you don't use individual array entries in your query processing. But by joining over array elements you certainly step over that line.

Answer (score 2):

The table you are referring to is more typically called a "junction" table or "association" table.  It is the standard way to implement many-to-many relationships.

Junction tables have some key advantages.  Notably, it guarantees data integrity when foreign keys are properly defined.

But that is not your question.  Are other representations appropriate under some circumstances?  I would say that Postgres provides powerful functionality through arrays and JSON which make them feasible for many-to-many relationships.  In particular, Postgres supports indexes on arrays and JSON, overcoming one of the big hurdles of such a relationship.

When would such a list be appropriate?  I don't think it is appropriate for `Actors`.  That is an entity in its own right and there is lots of additional information you want about an actor.

But it might be appropriate for something like user-generated tags, particularly tags where you don't feel a need to maintain a master list (and don't care about misspellings).  It might be appropriate for alternative names for something (assuming you don't want disjoint names across rows).

Comment: @RaphaelRafatpanah . . . Is there a reason you unaccepted this for another answer that gives similar advice?

Comment: Yes. the reason is that the accepted answer also mentions how the SQL queries themselves might have added complexity given the alternative approach, which is information enough that I feel warrants the accepted answer her. That being said, I feel that an example or two may make that point even clearer.